# How can I add values to an embedded set in Spring Data Redis

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-redis

I am writing a small chat-like application which has basically two entities "rooms" and "users". Data is stored within Redis since is has a very short lifetime, and since I want to familiarize with it.

The two data structures look simplified as follows.

**Room.java**

```java
import lombok.Data;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Reference;
import org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisHash;

import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import java.util.List;

@RedisHash("rooms")
@Data
public class Room {

    @Id
    private final String id;

    private final String name;

    @Reference
    private final List<User> participants;

    ...
}
```

**User.java**

```java
import lombok.Data;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisHash;

@RedisHash("users")
@Data
public class User {

    @Id
    private final Long id;

    private final String username;

    ...
}
```

Now I want to implement a `joinRoom(String roomId, User user)` method which should append the given user to the room's participants set.

My first attempt was to like this:

- read the current room
- id the room's participants list does not contain the user, add it
- save back the room

I think this solution screams bad idea, since the application will be running on multiple nodes in parallel and it is only a matter of time to see a race condition here.

It thought I might be able to use a [Partialupdate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-redis/docs/current/reference/html/#redis.repositories.partial-updates) but cannot find anything if it's possible to append to embedded lists, sets or similar.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Redisson as a Redis client you should take a look at [RLock](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.redisson/redisson/3.11.1/org/redisson/api/RLock.html) implementation that [can be received](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.redisson/redisson/3.11.1/org/redisson/api/RedissonClient.html#getLock-java.lang.String-) from the client.

Redisson locks fit for the distributed use case.

Comment: Nice, thank you! I will have a look at it.